# How to display an Image when user Click on button Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-storage

I have been trying to make a user press on a button to upload his/her image into Firebase Storage. It worked because I printed the result out.

```
flutter: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com:443/v0/b/libraryapp-a805e.appspot.com/o/userPFP%2FIMG_0008.JPG?alt=media&token=fee1f918-5608-467d-8889-0f22853f02b1
```

And this is the code for the function :

```
 Future uploadFile() async {
    if (file == null)
      return;
    else {
      final fileName = Path.basename(file!.path);
      final destination = 'userPFP/$fileName';
      var task = DatabaseServices.uploadFile(destination, file!);
      if (task == null)
        return;
      else {
        final snapshot = await task.whenComplete(() {});
        final urlDownload = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
        imageUrl = urlDownload;
        print(imageUrl);

      }
    }
  }
```

I called this function when I press on a button , this one :

```
child: TextButton(
    onPressed: () async {
    selectFile();
    uploadFile();
    print(
      'File Selected Succesful');
    },
```

But the image won't show instantly. I have to close the form out , and then open it back again , then the image shows. But I want the image to show whenever I press that button.

[image: This is immediately after I press the "Upload Picture" button]

[image: Here, the image shows, but not until I closed the form and opened it again]

Any help is appreciated ! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Would you try call after upload is completed to rebuild?

```
child: TextButton(
    onPressed: () async {
      selectFile();
      await uploadFile();
      print(
        'File Selected Succesful');
      },
      setState(() {});
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
setState(() {
   imageUrl = urlDownload;
});
```